# Asp.net web api oauth cors results in 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Following is the code. When I make an separate request using postman to "/token" it works. But when I call from a client side code, it fails with 400 bad request. When I debug I can see that the "GrantResourceOwnerCredentials" method is not getting hit. Any idea?

**Client Code**

```
return this.$http({
            url: this.config.remoteUri.account.login,
            method: "POST",
            data: { UserName: user.name, Password: user.password, grant_type: "password" },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // $scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //  $scope.status = status;
        });
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),                
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                Provider = new ActiveDirectoryAuthorizationProvider()
            };
            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

        }
    }
```

**Webapi Config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

Authorization Filter

```
public class ActiveDirectoryAuthorizationProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsTokenEndpoint && context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "authorization" });
            context.RequestCompleted();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

Comment: Have you found where was the issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Origin header has to be set on your outgoing request (OPTIONS+POST)

I've seen this implementation of the filter in other threads but here is mine which is in fact working for me - local and production server:

```
 public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsTokenEndpoint && context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {

            if (!context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Keys.Contains("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"))
                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["allowedOrigin"] });

            if (!context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Keys.Contains("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"))
                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Accept", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Pragma", "Origin" });
            if (!context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Keys.Contains("Access-Control-Allow-Methods"))
                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" });
            context.MatchesTokenEndpoint();
            context.RequestCompleted();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
    }
```

If you still have issues please respond with more details. Please note that AppendCommaSeparatedValues is required for this to work under IE and Edge

Comment: am also getting the same after i made this fix. anyone help?